# Unable to update Server2003 Forrest Functional Level - get error

Tags: windows-server-2003, domaincontroller

I am stuck with adding a Windows 2016 DC to my 2003 domain - Windows 2003 R2 32bit is the current Domain Controller. I am trying to add redundant DC functionality on my Windows 2016 Server. I am getting stuck at the part where I am supposed to update the Forrest and Domain Levels on the 2003 server.

Currently, the Domain Functional Level on 2003 is set to Windows 2003 (and says that this is the highest possible) but the Forrest Functional Level is blank. When I go to the Domains & Trusts and right click on the Active Directory (top level) and select raise Forest Level, I get a message: "mmc has detected an error in a snap-in" error during "Raising Forest Functional Level"

I have found that this is a known problem with a potential solution:

> "There was a similar thread on this cant find now, there is known issue with Win2003 Server with regards to schema snapin. This problem occurs because the Adsiedit.dll module uses an uninitialized pointer. When the system frees this pointer, some random data is freed. Therefore, an access violation may occur. Try this Hotfix and [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/946459"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/946459%22)

However, this kb article is no longer available on Microsoft, so I found it somewhere else but the kb946459 download is nowhere to be found.

Any help would be appreciated.